# cell values are the same but got FALSE when check them

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have this sheet :

[image]

Formula A1 :

```
=text(today(), "DD MM YYYY")
```

Formula B1 :

```
=text(today(), "DD MMM YYYY")
```

Formula A4 (check if A1 = A2) :

```
=A1=A2
```

Formula B4 (check if B1 = B2) :

```
=B1=B2
```

I have a 'copy' button on the right and assign my custom function to copy from A1 to A2 and B1 to B2 :

```
function copy() {
  Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  var val = Sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
  Sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(val)

  var val = Sheet.getRange("B1").getValue()
  Sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(val)  
}
```

The image above showing the result after I run the script. They look the exactly the same. but the B4 showing FALSE. What is wrong ?

I also tried to use 2 different names and change 'var' to 'const' :

```
function copy() {
  Sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  const val = Sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()
  Sheet.getRange("A2").setValue(val)
  const val2 = Sheet.getRange("B1").getValue()
  Sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(val2)  
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using two different variable names?

Comment: @Blindspots yes. but still the same. I also try to replace 'var' with 'const' with 2 different variable name, but no lucks.

Comment: I've just added the script using 2 variable names, tested with 'var' and 'const' as well , but still the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in cell `B2` is a numeric date, while the values in the other cells are text strings that just look like dates. A date is not equal to a text string even if they look the same. You can check the types of the four values with the `isnumber()` and `istext()` functions.

Google Sheets will automatically coerce text strings to numeric values when using `Range.setValue()` with a text string whose format matches one of the supported date, time, duration, currency or Boolean formats. In the example you give, `27 Jan 2024` is a valid date format, while `27 01 2024` is not. The former will be coerced to a numeric date and the latter will stay a text string.

To find whether two values *look the same*, use this pattern:

```
=to_text(B1) = to_text(B2)
```